# Find maximum in sorted and rotated array

Tags: java, performance, interview-questions, complexity, binary-search

This is an interview question.
A sorted rotated array is a sorted array which was rotated 0 or more times.

For example: `[1,2,3] -> [2,3,1]`

Please tell me what do you think about the following (correctness, efficiency, coding conventions) and specifically if I can remove in some way the special handle for array of two elements:

```
static int findMax(int arr[]) { 
    return findMax(arr, 0 , arr.length - 1); 
} 

static int findMax(int arr[], int low, int high) {
    int middle;

    if (low == high) {
        return arr[low];
    }
    if ( Math.abs(high - low) == 1 ) {
        return Math.max(arr[low], arr[high]);
    }

    middle = (low + high) >> 1;
    if (arr[middle] > arr[middle + 1]) {
        return arr[middle];
    }
    if (arr[low] > arr[middle]) {
        return findMax(arr, low, middle - 1);
    }
    return findMax(arr, middle + 1, high);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Have you tested this? How? Does it pass your tests? What made you write this? Please add more context. More context => better questions => better answers.

Comment: Yes, I wrote some nine tests which passed (different array cases). I wrote that because it's an interview question I saw in some site (preparation for an interview).

Comment: Somebody defaced your question and you accepted it. Please don't. The additional context was helpful and shouln't have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

- `Math.abs` in `Math.abs(high - low) == 1` is suspicious. `high` *should* always be not less than `low`. Remove it.
- `middle = (low + high) >> 1` [may (and will) overflow](https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html). Do `middle = low + (high - low) >> 1`.

  That said, `>> 1` is no better than) `/ 2`.
- Java is notorious in *not* eliminating the tail recursion. You should do it manually. First, rewrite it in a tail-recursive form:

  ```
      if (low == high) {
          return arr[low];
      }
      if ( Math.abs(high - low) == 1 ) {
          return Math.max(arr[low], arr[high]);
      }

      middle = (low + high) >> 1;
      if (arr[middle] > arr[middle + 1]) {
          return arr[middle];
      }
      if (arr[low] > arr[middle]) {
          high = middle - 1;
      } else {
          low = middle + 1;
      }
      return findMax(arr, low, high);
  ```

  then eliminate a recursive call:

  ```
      while (high - low > 2) {
          middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
          if (arr[middle] > arr[middle + 1]) {
              return arr[middle];
          }
          if (arr[low] > arr[middle]) {
              high = middle - 1;
          } else {
              low = middle + 1;
          }
      }
      return Math.max(arr[low], arr[high]);
  ```

Comment: This should have `while (high - low >= 2) {`.  Consider a three element array.  So `low` is 0 and `high` is 2; your code would `return Math.max(arr[0], arr[2]);` without ever entering the body of the loop.  And frankly, I think that's overcomplicating things.  The code works fine with `while (high > low) {` and `return arr[low];`.  No 2 or `Math.max` needed.